# how ng-app works with blank module in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, so please excuse me if it is very basic question :

Following code is working fine.So whatever I am typing in text box is getting printed on  the console as expected :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <body>
      <div >
         <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
         {{name}}
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

However ,if I change ng-app="" to ng-app=" " or any other text like ng-app="abc" in above code,it does not work.My understanding is that it expects a module with that name or with empty name,but then What does it mean when it is working with ng-app="".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good Question, many of us may not think why it is working. Let me explain here.

Here is an answer for your question.

Whenever you include `AngularJs` in your Project either by `script-tag` or through `Bower`, `npm` etc a file called `Angular.js` will get loaded.

This file has many functions as normal Js files contain. One of them is `angularInit`.

**angularInit:**

This function is responsible for detecting the `module name` given and will match this module name with `angular.module()`.

Have a look at `angulatInit function`.

```
function angularInit(element, bootstrap) {
  var appElement,
      module,
      config = {};

  // The element `element` has priority over any other element.
  forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'app';

    if (!appElement && element.hasAttribute && element.hasAttribute(name)) {
      appElement = element;
      module = element.getAttribute(name);
    }
  });
  forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'app';
    var candidate;

    if (!appElement && (candidate = element.querySelector('[' + name.replace(':', '\\:') + ']'))) {
      appElement = candidate;
      module = candidate.getAttribute(name);
    }
  });
  if (appElement) {
    if (!isAutoBootstrapAllowed) {
      window.console.error('AngularJS: disabling automatic bootstrap. <script> protocol indicates ' +
          'an extension, document.location.href does not match.');
      return;
    }
    config.strictDi = getNgAttribute(appElement, 'strict-di') !== null;
    bootstrap(appElement, module ? [module] : [], config);
  }
}
```

If we extract some part of that function,

```
 forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'app';

    if (!appElement && element.hasAttribute && element.hasAttribute(name)) {
      appElement = element;
      module = element.getAttribute(name);
    }
  });
```

**The above part is the place where the magic occurs.**

In that first see **`ngAttrPrefixes`** which is an `array`

**`var ngAttrPrefixes = ['ng-', 'data-ng-', 'ng:', 'x-ng-'];`**

**Explanation of that part of code:**

1. `ngAttrPrefixes` gets looped using `forEach` function.   `code: (forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {)`
2. we are searching for `ng-app` or 'data-ng-app' or 'ng:app' or  'x-ng-app' using `code: (var name = prefix + 'app')`
3. If an element contains any one of them, (Eg: ) `(code:  if (!appElement && element.hasAttribute && element.hasAttribute(name)) {)`
4. Assinging that element to a variable called appElement. `(code: appElement = element;)`
5. The value of that attribute is being stored in module. `(code: module = element.getAttribute(name);)`

So, `module` **variable** gets the value of `ng-app`.

After some lines of code, you can see a line,

**`bootstrap(appElement, module ? [module] : [], config);`**

**Here the angular bootstraps the application using `ng-app`**

the code, `module ? [module] : []` says that,

**If**

there is a value in `module` variable which **we have seen above**. then take `[module]` in an array and search for that module.

**else**

take `[]` and executes code without searching for module.

So,

**If ng-app = "myApp", then module will be `myApp` and it will search for `myApp` module in `angular.element("myApp")`**

`Eg: <div ng-app="myApp">`

**If `ng-app = "" or ng-app`, then module will be `""` the value will be `[]`**

`Eg: <div ng-app="">` / `Eg: <div ng-app>`

So, it will execute without searching for module.

Conclusion from the above code:

**So, if `ng-app=""`, the condition `module ? [module] : []` will fail and result will be `[]` and will not search for module. This line answers your question.**

**Edit on your comment:**

The ternary operator does not check only `boolean's`, it checks for the presence of the particular variable.

Eg:

```js
var a = "Present"

a ? console.log("a is present but not boolean") : console.log("a is absent")
```

**Please run the above example to clarify your doubt.**

Comment: Thanks for answering in detail.I have one doubt. Should not module variable have Boolean value(true or false) in this expression -> module ? [module] : []

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score -2):

check below code for this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="" >
      <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    {{name}}
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?